# Do there exist complex algebraic $α,β$ such that $α^β=π$ or $α^β=e$?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, exponential-function, pi

Given the algebraic operations and complex exponentiation $(a+bi)^{c+di}$ and logarithm, is it possible to derive $\pi$ and $e$?

If one is derivable then so should be the other, as $e^\pi = (-1)^{-i}$. I however don't think either are. I'd be interested to be proved wrong though.

An elaboration of the rules: no trigonometry, solution must be expressible using a finite number of terms, and $α$ and $β$ are complex, algebraic numbers.

Comment: You need to elaborate more. What counts as an algebraic operation? What values can $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ take?

Comment: @HenryT.Horton By algebraic operation I mean `any one of the operations addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, raising to an integer power, and taking roots (fractional power)`. $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are all real.

Comment: Then you need to specify what you mean by derivable. Otherwise we can just take $a = e$ or $\pi$, $c = 1$, and $b = d = 0$. Perhaps you mean to have stronger restrictions on $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

Comment: You want some restriction on $a,b,c,d$ beyond just being real.  For example, they should not be $\pi$ or $e$.

Comment: I think one reasonable restriction on $a,b,c,d$ would be that they be algebraic numbers. So the question would be if there exist $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ two algebraic numbers such that $\alpha^{\beta} = \pi$ or $\alpha^{\beta} = e$.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to extract $\pi$ or $e$ from the expression you gave when given the other?

Comment: @JoelCohen Thanks, I wasn't quite sure how to word it. I've updated the question.

Comment: @dfeuer I'd omitted allowing logarithms from the question – apologies. I've clarified though that $e^\pi = (-1)^{-i}$ is what I had in mind to derive one, given the other.

Comment: The wording is extremely confusing. Are you looking for real numbers, complex numbers, both? I don't understand. I assume you mean *complex* algebraic numbers, from what you wrote before, but I dunno.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $e$ is expressible like that if and only if there is an algebraic number not equal to $1$ whose natural logarithm is also algebraic, or, equivalently, iff there is an algebraic number other than zero whose exponential is algebraic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we allow natural logarithms, then $\pi=-i\cdot\ln(-1)$. If not, and/or if we restrict the domain to algebraic reals $(\mathbb{A}\cap\mathbb{R})$, then I believe the question to be still open/undecided. We know, from the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond-Schneider_theorem), that $a^b$ is transcendental, for *a*, *b* $\in\mathbb{A}$, with *a* $\neq0,1$, and *b* $\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. But since algebraics are [countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set), whereas transcendentals aren't, it follows that [almost all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) $\mathbb{T}$ numbers are *not* of the form $a^b$, with *a*, *b* $\in\mathbb{A}$, so there would be nothing surprising if it somebody were to ultimately prove that π and *e* could not be written in this manner. If such remarkable expressions for *e* or π would had been discovered by now, we'd undoubtedly have heard of them; and if a proof of their impossibility had already been established, it would've been as famous and well-known a theorem as that of *Gelfond* and *Schneider*, which I mentioned just earlier. That's why I said that the question is still open. Hope this answer helps to set things a bit more in perspective.